# Firewall won't work on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, firewall

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and firewall won't work on my device.

I get this message when trying to start firewall with `systemctl start firewall`:

```
root@agent:/usr/bin# systemctl start firewall
Job for firewall.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status firewall.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

root@agent:/usr/bin# systemctl status firewall
● firewall.service - apply firewall rules at startup
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/firewall.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-07-24 14:54:56 CEST; 39s ago
  Process: 816 ExecStart=/etc/firewall (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jul 24 14:54:56 agent systemd[1]: Starting apply firewall rules at startup...
Jul 24 14:54:56 agent systemd[1]: firewall.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Jul 24 14:54:56 agent systemd[1]: Failed to start apply firewall rules at startup.
Jul 24 14:54:56 agent systemd[1]: firewall.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 24 14:54:56 agent systemd[1]: firewall.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: I have never heard of a service simply called `firewall`. Please provide more information on what you are actually using  to implement your "firewall".

Answer (score 1):

`firewall` is not the service name to handle for the 'firewall' - we also don't use `firewalld` by default in 20.04 either.

The default firewall service in Ubuntu 20.04 is `ufw` - Uncomplicated Firewall.

You control `ufw` by commands on the command line.

To enable `ufw` just run `sudo ufw enable` and it should default to a permit-outbound deny-unrelated-inbound type policy.

To configure `ufw` please read the manpage of `ufw` - `man ufw` - for details on the commands, etc. to manipulate the firewall rules.

Comment: I did find many hits on search engines for "systemctl start firewall.service", but still haven't figured out what the actual underlying stuff is. maybe just iptables, not sure. Just F.Y.I.

Comment: @DougSmythies that's usually for RHEL systems - they use `firewall` instead of `ufw` or such directly.  RHEL/CentOS systems are completely different than Ubuntu though :P

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did observe mostly RHEL and CentOS in the various "hits", but also saw some git hub stuff, perhaps people doing their own thing.